# How do I load the iOS Calendar App from a button push in iOS 8.1 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8.1

What I'm wanting to do is load the iOS calendar app from a button push, the only ways I've found so far require objective-C and I'm trying to stay away from that.  Is the URL scheme still an option using Swift for example using the "calshow://" option, the way I've found to do it in Obj-C is as follows:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"calshow://"]];
```

In terms of my project here's the setup I've got:

```
   @IBAction func openCalendar(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a whole lot different in Swift. A literal translation would be:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "calshow://")!)`